# PHP 7.4 or 8.08 on MAC what to install (For mamp)

Tags: php, mamp

What would be the best version to install 7.4 or 8.08? All I want to do is make a basic website, so I know 7.4 will suffice. Just curious if there is anything big I'm missing out on, I also cannot find where to install 8.08

Comment: Both those versions are out of date. Why would you consider either for a new project?

Comment: Mamp only offers 7.4 and 8.08.

I also am making a vintage website: similar to smoething like http://www.neuhaus.it/english/

Answer (score 1):

Always prefer installing the latest version of the php as many things get deprecated in the older version and after some time some libraries may stop supporting your php version and you may not able to integrate your third party services. Also try to keep your software upgraded to the latest version. Also I feel mamp gives update really late. Some of the tasks are easy to do in mamp like port change and all but if you prefer xampp than you can get the latest version. but everything has their prons and cons. Xampp doesn't allow upgrading to latest version but mamp does so if you want to upgrade in xampp than you have to again install it.